# Pandas: Display One Row per Column Value based on Date

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe `df` which prints as follows:

```
    Order                        Report Name        Last Updated
6       1                 Fund Balance Sheet  Sep 11 10:36:28 AM
15      1                 Fund Balance Sheet  Sep 08 11:07:22 AM
14      2  Fund Income Statement - Operating  Sep 11 10:39:39 AM
3       2  Fund Income Statement - Operating  Sep 08 10:55:17 AM
5       3    Fund Income Statement - Reserve  Sep 11 10:49:38 AM
0       3    Fund Income Statement - Reserve  Sep 08 11:09:14 AM
4       4                     General Ledger  Sep 11 10:40:26 AM
13      4                     General Ledger  Sep 08 11:10:13 AM
12      5                   Expense Register  Sep 11 11:03:21 AM
8       5                   Expense Register  Sep 08 10:50:13 AM
7       6              Aged Payables Summary  Sep 11 10:42:19 AM
11      6              Aged Payables Summary  Sep 08 11:09:11 AM
2       7       Homeowner Prepayment Balance  Sep 11 10:36:01 AM
10      7       Homeowner Prepayment Balance  Sep 08 11:02:10 AM
1       8              Homeowner Delinquency  Sep 11 10:40:20 AM
9       8              Homeowner Delinquency  Sep 08 10:58:13 AM
```

How do I go about outputting a new df, still ordered by the `order` column, which only contains rows for the most recently updated report by each name? For example, with the above input, I'd like the output to be:

```
    Order                        Report Name        Last Updated
6       1                 Fund Balance Sheet  Sep 11 10:36:28 AM
14      2  Fund Income Statement - Operating  Sep 11 10:39:39 AM
5       3    Fund Income Statement - Reserve  Sep 11 10:49:38 AM
4       4                     General Ledger  Sep 11 10:40:26 AM
12      5                   Expense Register  Sep 11 11:03:21 AM
7       6              Aged Payables Summary  Sep 11 10:42:19 AM
2       7       Homeowner Prepayment Balance  Sep 11 10:36:01 AM
1       8              Homeowner Delinquency  Sep 11 10:40:20 AM
```

Notice that all the 9/11 reports were kept, and the 9/8 reports removed. Is there any way to do this other than with tons of looping and `max` type functions?

Comment: Do you know group by ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no year on there, so I'm assuming the years are all the same?

Sort the dataframe by the `'Last Updated'`. Then `drop_duplicates` and keep the last.

```
df = df.sort_values('Last Updated')
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset = 'Report Name', keep='last')
```

Assuming years are the same:

```
import pandas as pd


cols = ['Order','Report Name','Last Updated']

data =  [   
[1,                 'Fund Balance Sheet',  'Sep 11 10:36:28 AM'],
[1,                 'Fund Balance Sheet',  'Sep 08 11:07:22 AM'],
[2,  'Fund Income Statement - Operating',  'Sep 11 10:39:39 AM'],
[2,  'Fund Income Statement - Operating',  'Sep 08 10:55:17 AM'],
[3,    'Fund Income Statement - Reserve',  'Sep 11 10:49:38 AM'],
[3,    'Fund Income Statement - Reserve',  'Sep 08 11:09:14 AM'],
[4,                     'General Ledger',  'Sep 11 10:40:26 AM'],
[4,                     'General Ledger',  'Sep 08 11:10:13 AM'],
[5,                   'Expense Register',  'Sep 11 11:03:21 AM'],
[5,                   'Expense Register',  'Sep 08 10:50:13 AM'],
[6,              'Aged Payables Summary',  'Sep 11 10:42:19 AM'],
[6,              'Aged Payables Summary',  'Sep 08 11:09:11 AM'],
[7,       'Homeowner Prepayment Balance',  'Sep 11 10:36:01 AM'],
[7,       'Homeowner Prepayment Balance',  'Sep 08 11:02:10 AM'],
[8,              'Homeowner Delinquency',  'Sep 11 10:40:20 AM'],
[8,              'Homeowner Delinquency',  'Sep 08 10:58:13 AM']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
df['Last Updated'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Last Updated'], format="%b %d %I:%M:%S %p")

df = df.sort_values('Last Updated')
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset = 'Report Name', keep='last')
df['Last Updated'] = df['Last Updated'].dt.strftime('%b %d %I:%M:%S %p')
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
    Order                        Report Name        Last Updated
12      7       Homeowner Prepayment Balance  Sep 11 10:36:01 AM
0       1                 Fund Balance Sheet  Sep 11 10:36:28 AM
2       2  Fund Income Statement - Operating  Sep 11 10:39:39 AM
14      8              Homeowner Delinquency  Sep 11 10:40:20 AM
6       4                     General Ledger  Sep 11 10:40:26 AM
10      6              Aged Payables Summary  Sep 11 10:42:19 AM
4       3    Fund Income Statement - Reserve  Sep 11 10:49:38 AM
8       5                   Expense Register  Sep 11 11:03:21 AM
```

Comment: `Last Updated` is string. The sorting order is alphabetical, not canonical. Need to convert it to `Timestamp` first

Comment: @CodeDifferent tough if there's no year. But yes, I am making the assumption here that there's no other month than `Sep`. But to your point, it would require converting to datetime object, so I added that in the solution.

Comment: @chitown88 they actually are `datetime` objects, I'm just converting to a string earlier in my code for cleaner display, so I can use your solution prior to calling `strftime` on the column. Thanks!

Comment: Yup. That’s exactly what I would do then.